# Is there an equivalent of .lnk in Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, shortcuts

When creating a shortcut in windows it makes a `.lnk` file.

I have researched and it seems these are openable in linux(with some tweaking). Does Linux have an equivalent? If so, whats the extension?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Linux doesn't work with file extensions. However, you can make a shortcut on Linux using "symbolic links". They are something like a "pointer" to a file.

Take a look at [here](http://help.hardhathosting.com/question.php/95) to see how to do it:

> How do I create a symbolic link?
>
> ```
> ln -s [TARGET DIRECTORY OR FILE] ./[SHORTCUT]
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> ln -s /usr/local/apache/logs ./logs
> ```

Comment: However, unlike a Windows shortcut, a symbolic link will break when the target file is moved... which is pretty much the principal reason you'd use a shortcut. So strictly speaking a linux symlink is not the equivalent of a Windows shortcut, it's the equivalent of a Windows symlink.

Comment: Symlinks are my favorite tool for keeping my files organized. Linux symlinks are kept in sync with the target file no matter what program reads them!

Comment: @FactorMystic If you make the symlink point to an absolute location in the filesystem, this is not the case. `ln -s /usr/local/apache/logs ./logs` will make a symlink to `/usr/local/apache/logs`, and will not be broken when you move it around.

Comment: The environment maintains the symbolic links in the path, but Windows changes the environment's path for shortcuts. (E.g., if a link targets `/tmp` and resides in the file `/home/user/temp`, a symbolic link would access the directory `/tmp/upload` as `/home/user/temp/upload`, whereas a shortcut would first change the environment directory to `/tmp` and then access `/tmp/upload` directly.) I don't know of any Linux feature that behaves this way.

Comment: @FactorMystic If you move the target of a shortcut, then it will always break. If you move the link (symlink or shortcut), it may break, and this depends on a number of factors. More just the link: symlink with absolute path and shortcut will be fine; symlink with relative path will break. Move link and target together (i.e. whose sub-tree)  symlink with absolute path and shortcut will break, symlink with relative path will be fine. [so the comparison is not between symlink and shortcut, but between relative and absolute path.]

Answer (score 29):

Linux has two types of links:

- **`.desktop` files:** created by graphical file managers. They are similar to Windows `.lnk` shortcuts, minus the automatic updating. They, like shortcuts, only work inside the GUI file manager program.
- **Symbolic links:** created with **`ln -s target link`** on Linux and **`mklink link target`** on Windows. These can be used transparently by any program.

Comment: Oh, the superiority of Posix-based systems!

Comment: @Roy: There's always Plan9.

Comment: That looks interesting, @grawity. I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: there is the third one, hard link

Comment: @Lie: Yes, but it's not very widely used as a `.lnk` alternative due to the limitations.